# Having issues getting a percentage of a number in iOS 7.1 applicaion xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7.1

In my iOS 7.1 application that I'm trying to develop, I need to figure out percentages of a specific number which is entered in a UITextField. It would appear when executing the code I get the wrong percentage of that number entered.

I've tried two different ways to get the require percentage answer I'm looking for, however it keeps giving the wrong answer.

Below here is the two methods that I've tried.

For example I want to get 72% of 250. If you were to do this on a calculator or better yet a excel spreadsheet I get the right answer 250 x 1 - 72% = 70. This is the correct answer I want

Method1 (.m file) Not working

Values that are set the the specific .text parameters:

```
Entered in the UITextField _linuxOracleOnDiskw_oRTC.text = 250
Value set to UITextField _formulaNumber.text = 1
Percentage Value set to _linuxOracle_Percent.text = 0.72 

_linuxOracleOnDiskwithRTC.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", ([_linuxOracleOnDiskw_oRTC.text doubleValue])*([_formulaNumber.text doubleValue])-([_linuxOracle_Percent.text doubleValue])];
```

When executed I the answer or vale that gets entered in the UITextField _linuxOracleOnDiskwithRTC.text is 249.28. This is wrong should be 70

Second method tried is as follows:

```
float linuxOracleOnDiskw_oRTC = [_linuxOracleOnDiskw_oRTC.text floatValue];
```

_linuxOracleOnDiskwithRTC.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", (linuxOracleOnDiskw_oRTC * 1 -  72/100.0f )];

If someone can tell me what I maybe doing wrong and point me in the right direction with calculating percentages of a specific number entered in a UITextField I would be extremely GREATFUL.

Comment: do you mind reformatting correctly your message ? It is quite hard to read right now :)

Comment: 72% of 250 is **not** 70, it is 180. You need to go back to grade school math for a refresher.

Comment: Do you mean 72% _of_ 250, or do you mean 72% _off_ 250?

Comment: PEMDAS! learn it! and % in programming is for modulus math.

Answer (score 3):

Don't omit your brackets when performing calculations with code. For "250 x 1 - 72%" to get 70, you need to do this:

250 x (1 - 0.72) = 250 x 0.28 = 70

Formulas in () will be calculated first, followed by multiplication and division (whichever first), then followed by addition and subtraction (whichever first). So, insert your brackets appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

Your formula to calculate the percentage is incorrect. One correct way to calculate percentages is

250 / 100 x 72

This gives you 72% of 250. The result of that isn't 70, btw, but 180. If you want 70, then you don't want 72% but 28% (or 100% - 72%):

250 / 100 x (100 - 72)

Comment: Actually `250 / 100 * 72` will produce 144 and `250 / 100 * (100 - 72)` will produce 56 due to integer rounding. One way to prevent the rounding errors is to divide by 100 last: `250 * 72 / 100` and `250 * (100 - 72) / 100`. Another is to use floats.

Comment: The poster is using floats (and doubles) as far as I see in the code samples he posted.

Comment: Err, where do I mention anything about integers? I am showing math formulas, not code. Notice the absent code formatting (which you used, but I didn't).

Comment: You are making things up. * is a perfectly valid mathematical multiplication symbol that is in no way reserved to programming.http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/multiplication+sign. I have changed it to x for you, because I like making people happy.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments!  Greatly appreciated! Got all working!

Comment: Here is my code that works.   float total = [_linuxOracleOnDiskw_oRTC.text floatValue];
                float percent = [_linuxOracle_Percent.text floatValue] / 100.0f;
                float formulaNumber = [_formulaNumber.text floatValue];
                float answer = total * formulaNumber - percent * total;
                _linuxOracleOnDiskwithRTC.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", answer];